# Why can I not overwrite my wrapper in CSS?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, wrapper

Trying to make my website responsive and want to specify @media queries for mobile phones.

I have set a wrapper on my full body on each site to centre the content.

I set a new wrapper in @media but want to move the table a little more to the left. Nothing seems to move the table though. Tried setting margin left/right and different positioning. What else could I try?

Full CSS for my @media query:

```css
body {
  background-color: #d5e6b3;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  background-image: url(../img/backgroundt.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;
}

thead tr {
  background-color: #a0d93f;
}

td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
}

tbody tr:first-child {
  background-color: #707fe0;
}

tbody tr:nth-last-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #949feb;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  background-color: #707fe0;
}

@media(max-width: 500px) {
  html,
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  body {
    position: relative
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .table {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>About me</h1>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Skills</th>
        <th>Years of Experience</th>
        <th>Levels of Experience</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>HTML</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Beginner</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CSS</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Beginner</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>JavaScript</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Beginner</td>
    </tbody>
  </table><br>
  <br>
```

Comment: can you post the code outside of the media query?

Comment: It's generally easier to start with a mobile-first approach and add in desktop styles with min-width media queries

Comment: @kess Quite long but just created a CodePen of the full CSS here: https://codepen.io/halatinn/pen/YzYYxOo

Comment: While a supplementary Codepen is fine, when writing a question one should really strive to have a [mcve] in the body of the question itself; [only linking to the salient code offsite is considered insufficient for a SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/6831341).

Comment: put html and css codes in `codepen`

Comment: @M.RMRF Done! Noted, just hard to limit the amount of code for the question here as I do not know where the fault lies in this case, within the full code

Comment: remove `width` in line 28 .  and replace `width` with `min-width` in line 260

Comment: @M.RMRF Thanks for your reply! That would de-centre my whole other website (outside of the @ media query for smaller devices) though so that wouldn't work unfortunately..

Comment: `max-width: 750` must be `max-width: 750px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this.

The table did not align correctly with various px of left-margin or right-margin, neither did with margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto or padding on the left or right. However, using flex and flex-wrap to align the table head with the table body worked and centred the table for mobile devices.

The change can be seen when opening it with Web Dev tools on devices with max-width: 500px.

```css
body {
  background-color: #d5e6b3;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  font-weight: 700;
  color:  #000;
  background-image: url(../img/backgroundt.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1200px;

}


thead tr {
  background-color: #a0d93f;
}

td {
  padding: 12px 15px;
}

tbody tr:first-child {
  background-color: #707fe0;
}

tbody tr:nth-last-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #949feb;
}

tbody tr:last-child {
  background-color: #707fe0;
}


@media(max-width: 500px) {

  html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  body {
    position: relative
  }

  .wrapper {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .table {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    }
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
  </head>

    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
          <h1>About me</h1>

  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Skills</th>
        <th>Years of Experience</th>
        <th>Levels of Experience</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>HTML</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Beginner</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CSS</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Beginner</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>JavaScript</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Beginner</td>
    </tbody>
  </table><br>
  <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your table is 0 margin and there is no spacing on left, try to add in negative margin:

```
table {
  margin: -5px
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That did not result in any change unfortunately